# If Statement To Check Dates

Tags: c#

I have an 'IF' statement but I want the condition to check that the date of my object is not less than todays date but I can not figure out how to do this at all.

**Code**

```
private List<Web.Services.Entities.Generic.Expenditure> getTransactions(int Id, int AccountId, string Identifier)
{    
if (Details != null)
    {
    foreach (var ABC in Details.Info.ABC)
    {
        if (ABC.Type == "Test" && ABC.Value.Value > 0)
        {
            int j = 1;

            if (ABC.Frequency == "Monthly")
            {
                j = 3;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < j; i++)
            {
                List.Add(new Web.Services.Entities.Generic.Expenditure
                {
                    Amount = ABC.RegularIncome.Value * -1,
                    Description = "Income (" + ABC.Frequency + ")",
                    DueDate = (DateTime)ABC.NextDate.Value.AddMonths(i)
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I tried to declare my `(DateTime)ABC.NextDate.Value` as a `VAR` above the following `IF` and then add to `if (ABC.Type == "ABC" && ABC.Value.Value > 0)` but I got the following error:

> operator '&& ' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and
>   'system.datetime'

I need to add another condition to the above `IF` and not replace the '0' as this is checking another value in what is returned.

Comment: What is `ABC.Value.Value` and where exactly do you get the error (not an exception btw.)

Comment: Your question is confusing. Point out the line of code that is causing the error.

Comment: Can you post the line of code you tried which caused the error?

Comment: Can you show where `tranche.NextIncomePaymentDate` is declared?

Comment: Obviously `NextIncomePaymentDate` is a `Nullable`-type. Therefor you have to check for `NextIncomePaymentDate.Value.Date`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere apparantly he already has tried that and seems to get an `System.InvalidOperationException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test a nullable date you do the following:

```
if (dateTimeToBeTested.Value.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date)
```

By using the `.Date` property, you are forcing the `DateTime` to midnight of the date in question, so time differences will be ignored.

To use this in your example above, you can do the following:

```
if (ABC.Type == "Test" && ABC.Value.Value > 0 && dateTimeToBeTested.Value.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date)
```

Comment: Using your example I get the following error:  `System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @murday1983 ok so the datetime is nullable, have edited my answer to reflect the correct syntax.

Comment: I already tried your updated solution and that gives the following error `ABC.NextDate.Value' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException`

Comment: @murday1983 edit your question with the exact line of code you tried, as well as what you originally tried. Right now, without knowing what you tried to get the error, we are poking in the dark.

Comment: Turned out that one of my enteries was missing a date in my DB. Once added you solution worked

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime.Now` to compare `ABC.Value.Value` with current date.

```
  if (ABC.Type == "Test" && ABC.Value.Value > DateTime.Now)
```

**Edit** after question update with more required details and updated if statement.

> System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no
>   extension method 'Date' accepting...

You need to use DateTime.Value to access the Date property of nullable DateTime. Before using Date property you must check if DateTime variable has value. You can use `.HasValue` to ensure you have value for nullable DateTime.

Once you are sure that your datetime variable has values using `.HasValue` you can safely use DateProperty so you would use `ABC.NextDate.Value` instead of `ABC.NextDate` to access Date Property.

```
if (ABC.Type == "Test" && ABC.Value.Value > 0 && ABC.NextDate.HasValue && ABC.NextDate.Value.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date)
```

Comment: But his exception was `operator '&& ' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'system.datetime`. So `ABC.Value.Value` seems not to be a `DateTime`.

Comment: @Adil Sorry, the `ABC.Value.Value >` is doing another check to ensure that another value is not '0'. My date is coming from the `DueDate = (DateTime)ABC.NextDate.Value.AddMonths(i)`

Comment: What is type of ABC.Value.Value? as error says bool and DateTime?

Comment: @Adil `ABC.Value.Value` returns an amount so that condition is checking that the amount returned is not 0

Comment: You need to use Value property of nullable datetime to access Date property. Also use HasValue to ensure you have value of nullable datetime